How to access objects declared in my main Program.cs from a user control in Visual Studio
I have a user control named General_Inputs. I am attempting to access three different objects called OBJ_CurrentEngine, OBJ_CurrentGearBox and OBJ_CurrentChassis which are declared and initialized in my Program.cs after the user control is created and therefore I cannot pass these in as parameters.
I had a similar issue with a normal variable and I fixed this by making the variable global and accessing it in the user control like so:
protected bool FUNCT_GrabValuesHaveBeenLoaded //Gets the has been loaded boolean from main project
  {
      get { return (Engine_Simulator.Program.ValuesHaveBeenLoaded); }
  }

I also tried to make the objects public to access them the same way as above however the program then forces me to make them static which breaks the rest of my code:


Looks like you defined the static fields within a method. This is not possible, move them out of the method.

fyi Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
